# How to set Login.aspx page as the default page in an MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have added a aspx page in my MVC Application naming Login Page. But On Hosting it was not Setting as the default because the default page in IIS has been overridden by the route.config. How to set it aspx page in Route.config in an MVC application

On Hosting it was not Setting as the default because the default page in IIS has been overridden by the route.config

Answer (score 0):

> //I have Tried this and Its Working

```
public class RouteConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "../Login.aspx"
               //defaults: new { controller = "NOP", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
       }
   }
```

Comment: Instead, put the Authorize attribute on the Home controller, in fact all appropriate controllers that will redirect the user to the Login action.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps and you are good to go:**

1. Right-click your Project within the Solution Explorer.
2. Choose Properties.
3. Select the Web tab on the left-hand side.
4. Under the Start Page section, define the Specific Page you would
   like to default to when the application is launched.
5. Save your changes.

Another way is to add authorization attribute to  the controllers where you need to be logged in.

```
[Authorize]
public class somecontroller: BaseController
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @OP, you got it fixed??